# What are the possibilities of using Ionic with Sitecore?

Tags: ionic-framework, sitecore, sitecore8

I am a beginner in Sitecore and as well as Ionic Framework.I just wanted to know the possibilities of using Ionic with Sitecore. And I have no Idea where to start. Can some one help me about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to Sitecore, but have been working with Ionic for a few years now. According to an article written by Lars Nielsen (CDO for Sitecore) on the Sitecore site:

https://community.sitecore.net/general/blogs/business_blogs/b/technical_trends/posts/sitecore-as-a-true-headless-cms

It is a fully headless CMS, and you're able to do everything from login/logout, to retrieving and posting items via the API according to the docs:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/sitecoreservicesclient/the_restful_api_for_the_itemservice

If you're asking in reference to the Commerce piece of Sitecore, you might look at this documentation

http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DevOpsGuide/en-us/index.html#Concepts/c_M_Service%20API.html

which states:

> The Sitecore Commerce Service API is made up of three role-oriented
>   APIs, each targeting specific logically separated business needs:
>
> **CommerceOps API**: for the DevOps role in managing a Sitecore Commerce
>   implementation, including methods to create and manage Commerce
>   Environments and global policies.
>
> **CommerceShops API**: for supporting the online shopping experience such
>   as a web storefront. For example, when adding to a cart in the
>   Reference Storefront, the related processor in Sitecore Commerce
>   Connect makes an API call to the Commerce Engine to perform the cart
>   activity and return a result.
>
> **CommerceAuthoring API**: for business users. It introduces the "Entity
>   Views" concept, which is a mechanism for mapping potentially complex
>   Sitecore Commerce entities into a flattened structure that can be
>   dynamically represented in business tools.

-Ben